# dataserver design based on firebase for Mobile Apps

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I'm considering using Firebase as the main database for mobile based social network including only mobile clients (android, iOS). 
In the scenario of social network where each user is exposed to only limited amount of data within its friend circle Firebase actually works quite well. However I have certain concerns I wan't to clear up before any heavy lifting starts.

I have the messages and chat functionality where users can message to all his friends or selected friend group. Since each user have slightly different friend circle, the message (or notification with the reference) needs to go to each friend. 
My concern is if the user has 500 friends this would within the app generate 500 push requests to firebase with 500 different urls.
Alternatively I could store the chat/message in one place however receiving the message would mean to scan 500 different urls (all friends) to get the latest messages in the phone. Either way I end up with the same.

Do I have to be worried about app performance?

My second thought was to build the proxyserver which would take care of pushing notifications to friends so the app would send only one request for the server to push the message to all friends individually. But this would add up extra development work thus the cost to the project.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to de-normalize your data and put messages in people's inbox at the time they are created. We built an app called Firefeed to showcase this approach: http://firefeed.io/.

The basic concept is to create several copies of a message at creation time and send a copy to each of the recipients "inbox". Of course, this means that a sender cannot edit or delete after it is sent, but this might be an acceptable trade-off in most cases. (Note: It is technically possible to edit/delete a message, but it's a very expensive operation since you'll have to traverse your entire network to find the copies).

There's more about how to de-normalize your data in this blog post: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

Comment: Thanks, I've actually read the post already, but I'm still curious if sending a copy to each box would affect the performance considering it is all done on the client side, possibly through mobile network. We are talking about sending copy to hundreds or thousands recipients.